# How can I unstuck a transaction sent from Mycelium?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, mycelium-wallet, bittrex

My transaction has been unconfirmed for more than a week. 
I had a normal transaction fee (not low). 
The amount of the transaction was not small >0.5btc.
The inputs were not unconfirmed outputs.

The transaction came from a Mycelium wallet to a Bittrex wallet.
The Mycelium wallet has no option to increase the fee. 
The Bittrex wallet has no way to try to spend the unconfirmed outputs to create a CPFP transaction.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

---

<sup>*This is a complementary question to [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/5406) which answers the question's broader implications and proposes mitigation mostly focused on Bitcoin Core.*</sup>

Comment: I take it that your transaction had no change output that went back to your Mycelium wallet?

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: I assume your transaction was very large in bytes then. What was its size and what fee was paid? Anyway have you looked at this https://pool.viabtc.com/tools/txaccelerator/ ?

Answer (score 1):

First, find the transaction on a blockchain explorer like [blockchair.com](https://blockchair.com/) or [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/) and make sure it appears as valid. If it isn't found, it wasn't broadcast at all by your wallet, and you can find many free broadcast services [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_broadcasting).

Assuming it is valid, has been broadcast, then find a free transaction accelerator (don't bother paying the ones that ask for a fee) and enter the transaction ID and usually you'll see it get confirmed. I recommend the [ViaBTC Accelerator](https://pool.viabtc.com/tools/txaccelerator/)*  or creating an account at AntPool (free) and using the [AntPool accelerator](https://www.antpool.com/user/prioritiseTransaction.htm).

Be patient. It can still take a few hours or so.

---

* *You'll have to time it right. They only allow a handful per hour.*